# Curious question about inconsistence in python computing

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to learn Poisson distribution using Python.
I would like to generate a list of probabilities using list-comprehension.
the formula is guaranteed with no negative number returned.
however, when I used in list-comprehension below I got many negative numbers.

Would you please explain to me what I'm missing that causing the problem.
Please see the lines below for details.

Thank you, all.

```
import math
import numpy as np

lam = 15
a = np.arange(30)
b = [np.exp(-lam)*(lam**x)/math.factorial(x) for x in a]

[3.059023205018258e-07,
 4.588534807527386e-06,
 3.44140110564554e-05,
 0.000172070055282277,
 0.0006452627073085387,
 0.0019357881219256162,
 0.0048394703048140406,
 0.010370293510315801,
 -0.013141028594890315,
 -0.0001781617069955619,
 9.481664980368431e-05,
 -2.362463102985818e-06,
 -2.1020607345176417e-07,
 -3.1555253576611854e-08,
 -3.6677408619686507e-09,
 3.5112039118960344e-10,
 1.520183133726461e-11,
 -1.3618446037306896e-12,
 9.639826317732186e-14,
 4.996694908364656e-16,
 -1.6527804252450604e-16,
 1.052286501865168e-17,
 1.6130198477088384e-19,
 3.5537768829770886e-21,
 1.0354451630381044e-22,
 -2.257593163998853e-23,
 6.599657279663544e-27,
 3.666476266479747e-27,
 1.9641837141855786e-27,
 -2.4206987189043917e-29]
```

Answer (score 3):

The elements of `np.arange(30)` are `numpy.int64`s, which can overflow negative:

```
>>> a = np.arange(30)
>>> 15**a[19]
-4608176067875183057
```

For a list comprehension, you don’t need NumPy at all:

```
lam = 15
a = range(30)
b = [math.exp(-lam)*(lam**x)/math.factorial(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: The first community wiki i encounter un-intentionally.